# spring boot end point works with browser but not with postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am new to spring security, I have written test endpoint with google oauth2, I can authencitace with web browser and my end point works, but not working with postman,

here is my properties

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id={{CLIENT_ID}}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret={{SECRET}}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=openid,profile,email
```

Here is my controller

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping()
    public String get() {
        return "testing java 18";
    }
}
```

Here is my security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Login(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

with above configuration, if I test http://localhost:8080 on browser it redirects to google signing and the text `testing java 18` appears.

But when I use postman with below config

```
Type: `OAuth 2.0`
Add authorization to data to: `Request Header`

Configure New Token:
Token Name: {{SOME_RANDOM_NAME}}
Grant Type: `Authorization Code`
Callback URL: `https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback`
Auth URL: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`
Access Token URL: `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`
Client ID: `{{CLIENT_ID}}` same used in application.properties
Client Secret: `{{CLIENT_SECRET}}` same used in application.properties
Scope: `profile email openid`
State: empty
Client Authentication: `Send as basic auth header`
```

With above if I hit `Get New Access Token`, I do get new `Access Token` and `id_token` with google signing, after I hit `Use Token` I and send GET on the endpoint I get 403
Also If I use `id_token` and change Type to `Bearer Token` I get the same.

with older version If I use below Securityy config, Endpoint works when I send my id_token as Type to `Bearer Token`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = false)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
}
```

I tried searching in the forum but didn't; got much.